# How to delete lines from a file until a specific pattern?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to look up the line number of a specific match in a file – email address – and then delete it from the beginning of the file until the matched line.

**e.g** Let's say the line number is *13807*. So I need to keep the *13808*+ lines intact.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat input
some
lines
before
mail@server.com
and
some
more
afterwards

$ cat output
and
some
more
afterwards
```

Comment: I don't see a UBUNTU question here.   (simple) sed questions are best answered elsewhere, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed

Comment: You can delete a range of lines based on a search pattern directly e.g. `sed '1,/specific match/d' file.txt > newfile.txt` - there's no need to introduce an extra step of determining the line number of the match

Comment: @guiverc bash scripting questions are on topic here (see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic )

Comment: @guiverc Besides [that](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807), see [the help](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/47), [Are “not only Ubuntu-specific” questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523), [this dupe](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14663), [these answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17174), and "Respecting your own community" [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). When stating AU policy, I suggest *checking* first.

Comment: As steeldriver already pointed out the line number of the pattern doesn't matter, all the solutions below will just search for the first occurence of the pattern and output everything that comes after it.

Answer (score 14):

#sed

```
sed '1,/mail@server\.com/d'  # removing the matched line
sed '/mail@server\.com/,$!d' # keeping the matched line
```

###Explanations

- `1,/mail@server\.com/d` – `d`elete every line from line `1` to (`,`) `mail@server.com`
- `/mail@server\.com/,$!d` – don't (`!`) `d`elete every line from `mail@server.com` to (`,`) the end of the file (`$`), but everything else

###Usage

```
sed '…' file > file2 # save output in file2
sed -i.bak '…' file  # alter file in-place saving a backup as file.bak
sed -i '…' file      # alter file in-place without backup (caution!)
```

---

#awk

```
awk 'f;/mail@server\.com/{f=1}' # excluding the matched line
awk '/mail@server\.com/{f=1}f'  # including the matched line
```

###Explanations

- `f` – variable `f`, variables are `0` = `false` by default, `awk` prints nothing if the expression is `false` and just prints the line if the expression is `true`
- `/mail@server\.com/{f=1}` – if `mail@server.com` is found set `f=1`, therefore rendering the whole expression `true` the next time `f` occurs in the expression

###Usage

```
awk '…' file > file2                          # save output in file2
awk -iinplace -vINPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '…' file  # alter file in-place saving a backup as file.bak
awk -iinplace '…' file                        # alter file in-place without backup (caution!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` approachs, including the matched line.

```
awk '/pattern/, 0' infile
```

Excluding the matched line.

```
awk '/pattern/&& getline, 0' infile
```